# Find the source of an XMLHttpRequest using Chrome/Firefox dev tools

Tags: javascript, debugging, xmlhttprequest, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug a web application not written by me. There is a failing XMLHttpRequest being made:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '...' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Is there a way, preferably using Chrome developer tools, to locate the source of this call?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

It turns out - yes, there is. That "XHR Breakpoints" option on the side which I had always ignored:

[image]

It works perfectly.

Firefox has an identical feature:

[image]

Comment: Hell yeah... how come I missed using that feature.

Comment: It will stop you on XHR call, not the real function, for that keep pressing `Shift+F11` to step out of function call until you reach the start.